# Revisit summation involving log function and $\mu^2$ function.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logarithms

This is a self-answer question that was inspired by the
[following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4566711/finding-the-result-of-the-summation-containing-logarithm-and-mu-function/4566763).

For some reason, the OP (i.e. original poster) of the original question chose to
delete the question.  So, I am re-posting the question because I regard the
question as being of general interest.  I also regard the *Elbow Grease* solution as being of
general interest.

The original question is:  Evaluate

$$\sum_{d|n}\mu^2(d)log(d) ~: ~n \in Z^+.$$

See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$d = 1$ can be eliminated from consideration, because $\log(1) = 0.$

Also, $~\mu^2(d) = 1,~$ rather than $0$ if and only if $d$ is square free.
The summation may therefore be expressed as

$$\sum_{d > 1, ~d ~\text{is square free}, ~d|n} \log(d). \tag1 $$

(1) above may routinely be evaluated with $\color{red}{\text{Elbow Grease}}.$

Suppose that the prime factorization of $(n)$ is given by

$$n = p_1^{a_1} \times p_2^{a_2} \times p_3^{a_3}.$$

Then, the summation in (1) above becomes

$$\log(p_1) + \log(p_2) + \log(p_3)$$

$$+ [\log(p_1 + p_2)] + [\log(p_1) + \log(p_3)] + [\log(p_2) + \log(p_3)]$$

$$+ [\log(p_1) + \log(p_2) + \log(p_3)].$$

So, you have a symmetric expression where the coefficient applied to $\log(p_1)$ is $(4)$.  This makes perfect sense because, of the two primes $p_2, p_3$, there are $2^2$ possibilities as to whether $p_2$ and/or $p_3$ will be combined with $p_1$ to form a factor.

---

So, the pattern is clear.

Suppose that the prime factorization of $(n)$ is given by

$$n = p_1^{a_1} \times \cdots \times p_r^{a_r}.$$

Then

$$\sum_{d > 1, ~d ~\text{is square free}, ~d|n} \log(d)  $$

$$= 2^{(r-1)} \sum_{i=1}^r \log(p_i).$$

Comment: Does $\mu^2(d)=(1)$ mean something different than $\mu^2(d)=1$?

Comment: @Randall No, I intend it to mean the same thing.  Other experienced MathSE reviewers have criticized my over-use of parentheses.  My view is that for experienced reviewers, this is a mild annoyance and with new users (e.g. high school senior or college freshman) it sometimes prevents confusion.  Note the "...rather than $(0)$..." clause.  Expressing $1$ as $(1)$ makes a nice balance with this clause.

Comment: It's actually super confusing because you have an equation that's labelled as "(1)".  Maybe the oldsters are right.

Comment: @Randall That is an excellent rebuttal.  I therefore edited my answer.